# Imagemagic convert renders only some utf-8 symbols

Tags: fonts, unicode, imagemagick

Imagemagic's `convert` util ([render simple label](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label) feature) renders only some of utf-8 symbols.

Here is example:

```
convert -background white -fill black \
 -density 600x600 -size 1346x756 -font DejaVu-Sans -gravity center \
 'label:⌁ Electricity\n Chargers\n Powerbanks' \
 out.pdf # or out.png
```

[image]

It renders only ⌁ , not other ,  symbols.

What's the most handy, appropriate way to fit it and how:
should I install more fonts or use better font?

Comment: Cross references:
* https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/711
* https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32604

Comment: Cross linking: Made related question : [How to combine multiple fonts into one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45987676/544721)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use [Pango Markup language](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango_markup) to render fonts with missing glyphs:

```
convert -background white -fill black \                                                                                    
 -density 72 -pointsize 72 -gravity center \
 "pango:<span font='DejaVu-Sans'>⌁ Electricity\n Chargers\n Powerbanks</span>" \
 out.png
```

Pango renderer tries to use the specified font (`DejaVu-Sans`), but fallback to the system default if a glyph is missing. Probably, you may nest several `<span font='..'>..</span>` structures to have a hierarchy of font fallbacks.

Answer (score 3):

I've found font 'Symbola', so this works:

```
convert -background white -fill black \
 -density 600x600 -size 1346x756 -font Symbola -gravity center \
 'label:⌁ Electricity\n Chargers\n Powerbanks' \
 out_with_Symbola.png
```

Output:

[image]

Thanks for hints in:

- [this](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32604&p=149339) thread of imagemagick forum
- [Fonts article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts) on ArchLinux wiki
- [This unix.SE captured debugging effort](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124095/9689) with handy snippet for generating given label with all fonts to find out best ones